# BlackBerry 10 always returns true for LocationManager.isProviderEnabled()

Tags: android, blackberry-10, locationmanager

I've discovered a rather annoying bug in BlackBerry 10's `LocationManager` where `isProviderEnabled()` always returns `true`, despite location services being disabled. This problem is also [mentioned by a user on the BlackBerry support forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/How-to-get-GPS-Location/td-p/2141183), without any resolution.

```
LocationManager lm = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Log.d("LocationManager", "gps="+lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
Log.d("LocationManager", "network="+lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
```

Regardless of the location services setting, this yields:

> gps=true
>   network=true

I've also tried the pre-Froyo workaround, but also all location providers are always returned for `getAllProviders()`:

```
for (final String provider : lm.getAllProviders()) {
    if (provider.equals((LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.d("LocationManager", "gps=true"));
    } else if (provider.equals((LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.d("LocationManager", "network=true");
    }
}
```

This yields the same result.

What can I do to determine the state of BB10's location services?

Comment: Ummm... what exactly is your question?

Comment: Good point. I was curious if anybody had found some workaround for this.